# Scraping data from charts or tables created using Google Visualization tools using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from the tables and charts from this website:
https://www.portfoliovisualizer.com/fund-performance?s=y&symbol=MUB&symbols=VTEB&benchmark=VWITX&startDate=1%2F1%2F2015&endDate=1%2F31%2F2020

The site contains both static tables, which I can parse w/o any problem using requests and BeautifulSoup, and some dynamically generated tables and charts that are created through the use of Google Vizualization tools. 
For the dynamically generated parts, I used the Selenium webdriver, and was able to get the page source, after the dynamic charts and tables are being generated, so I see the values I am looking to pull. However, I do not know how to pull them, as they show in the page source in segments like the one below:

> Blockquote

```
    <div id="chartDiv2" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    <script>
    function getChartData2() {
    var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Year', 'Vanguard Tax-Exempt Bond ETF', 'iShares 
    National Muni Bond ETF', 'Vanguard Interm-Term Tx-Ex Inv'],['2015', 0.02622989191078684, 
    0.027694140180976934, 0.020218079771240793],['2016', 0.0017793103198122662, -0.0016512224730700353, 
    8.245768963E-4],['2017', 0.04691417159814648, 0.04723004573804612, 0.04534581696422735],['2018', 
    0.010468419206658197, 0.0092958557816043, 0.01252249494095059],['2019', 0.07344514685363279, 
    0.07055205700158873, 0.06781218369439523],['2020', 0.017556966753828895, 0.01659204635238365, 
    0.0158935038009671]]);
    var formatter2 = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ pattern: '0.00%' });
    formatter2.format(data2, 1);
    formatter2.format(data2, 2);
    formatter2.format(data2, 3);
    var chart2 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chartDiv2'));
    var options2 = { title: 'Annual Returns', legend: { textStyle: { fontSize: 13 } }, hAxis: { title: 
    'Year'}, vAxis: { dummy: false, title: 'Annual Return', format:'0.0%', minValue: 0}, focusTarget: 
    'category'};
    return [chart2, data2, options2];
    }
    </script>
```

> Blockquote

Any search of the soup with find or find_all stumbles at the outermost table (which seems to encompass the entire webpage). I am quite new at Python, so any help would be really appreciated. Right now, the only way I can think of doing this is saving the entire page source as a text file (which I have done) then parsing it myself by searching for each instance of google vizualization tools being used and proceeding from there). That would be quite tedious, and probably not very robust when trying to use it to another link.

Many thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: @mattsmith321, I am sorry if I wasn't clear, actually it is precisely the data in the table underlying the chart that I am trying to scrape, I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Got it. I was thinking about some of the other chart + table combos that PV has on the site. I didn't pay enough attention to the link you sent and that those charts don't have the corresponding data tables displayed. Updating my answer below.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info. How do I integrate the code below in BeautifulSoup? My novice understanding is that I need to retrieve an object from from the soup with the .find method, and then, inside that object, I run the code  below to retrieve relevant array. I haven't been able to retrieve the appropriate  object from the soup. Also, thanks for the Tiingo info, I wasn't aware of it, I'll take a look. I am looking at index funds, if their historical performance data is there, I can replicate the performance and risk  calculations. The Financial Goals on PV is harder to replicate.

Comment: I apologize. I didn't pay attention to the BeautifulSoup part of your question and was mainly focused on the Selenium aspect. I did not realize the BS was mainly a tool to process HTML and XML files and pull information from them. As such, you are correct, pulling what you want would be challenging. However, if you switched to using Python to manage a Selenium headless driver, you could have better results at accessing objects on the page and processing them. Maybe look at https://realpython.com/modern-web-automation-with-python-and-selenium/ for tips.

Comment: That is a very useful link for a newbie like me, I will study that in detail and hopefully it will point me in the right direction. Thank you very much for  taking the time to look into my question.

Answer (score 0):

The getChartData2() function renders the chart visualization as an SVG on the page. That is how the chart supports the interactive capabilities that you see as you mouse over the chart. You could try grabbing that SVG from the DOM and saving it as SVG to see if it will keep the chart without the interactivity. Or you may try saving it as a PNG. Not sure of the best approach.

May I ask what you are trying to accomplish? It may be easier to scrape the data from the tables and then use the data to generate your own charts and tables on your platform. You could even use the same Google Visualization tools.

And as another option, Tiingo is a stock market data platform that has an API that has really good free access levels. Rather than scraping from PV, you could integrate directly with Tiingo API to pull the data that you want.

Hope that helps!

Updated based on Cimerra's comment above:

Yes, pulling the data from the getChartData2() text would be challenging. Do you have access to executing any of the JavaScript on the page through your framework? When I open Chrome Developer tools for that page, I can call getChartData2() and three objects are returned. The 2nd object is the data2 object that you could in theory manipulate to get what you want out of it.

```
Tf: Array(6)
  0:
    c: Array(4)
      0: {v: "2015"}
      1: {v: 0.02622989191078684, f: "2.62%"}
      2: {v: 0.027694140180976934, f: "2.77%"}
      3: {v: 0.020218079771240793, f: "2.02%"}
```

If you still can't do that, I would suggest finding a source for the data (like Tiingo (free) or CSI Data (paid but is what PV uses)) and then performing your own calculations for what you need. The side benefit is that you then actually get immersed into the financial world and learn how all of these things are calculated.

Granted, that becomes pretty challenging and then you end up rebuilding a lot of what PV provides for you. I rebuilt a small part of PV in Google Sheets + Tiingo but in the end it was a brittle mess. PV just recently implemented a subscription model and I subscribed because it is an awesome site with awesome data and I don't want to spend all my time trying to recreate it.